# Unity Get Canvas UI Text position for gameobjects move destination

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine

Good day, I wanted to make my Mesh Text move to a position on my Canvas(UI) Text. I can't seem to make the Mesh Text to go on the position of the UI Text, It always give me the position on the editor's position(it appears to be a really big number) How can I accurately get the position of my UI Text and convert it, so that my Mesh Text can have it's proper destination in this case the position of the UI Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas elements in the editor are position such that 1 world unity = 1 pixel based on the size and resolution of your camera, thats why it is such a large number.  When you actually enter play mode however, all of that stuff just gets mapped onto the screen.

While your UI Text doesn't really have a world position (as far as I understand) because its a Canvas element (assuming you didn't set the canvas to use world positions), you could find out in general where it is by having an invisible plane attached in front of the camera, and doing raycasts to that particular point on the screen then using the result of that raycast as the position to move your Mesh Text to.

It may also help if we knew a bit more about what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @VonnCC Attach an empty to the camera which appears to be in the same place as the UI element (or do this in code via raycasting) and then have them fly towards that position.